# Rename [jsonschema] to [json-schema]

Tags: discussion, tags

Analogous to [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)/[xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema) it should be [json](/questions/tagged/json)/[json-schema](/questions/tagged/json-schema).

At the moment, there are only 12 questions with [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema), but since [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema) already exists I can't simply create [json-schema](/questions/tagged/json-schema) and retag those 12 questions.